# Using Model.objects.filter in Form prevents me from updating Model

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a form setup like this where I use the values from `TestModel` to create a select field in a form. However if I want to update the `TestModel` to add a new column, Django gives me a `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn` saying the new column is not found on the table and the stack trace points back to this form `ModelChoiceField`. Its not until I comment out this select that I am able to make the migration to the database.

So my question is there a better way to setup this `ModelChoiceField` where I don't have to comment it out to update the underlying model on the database? I'm using Django 4.0 and python 3.8 for reference.

```py
class TestModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    """
    Overwriting model choice field attribute to use
    a different __str__ representation than the default
    model
    """

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.test_field


class TestForm(forms.Form):

    first_select = TestModelChoiceField(
        queryset=TestModel.objects.filter(model_attribute__isnull=False),
        initial=TestModel.objects.filter(model_attribute__isnull=False)
        .filter(test_field="Yes")
        .first()
        .team_id,
        label="Field One:",
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to needing database access in a form like this, you're best waiting until the form is initialised rather than at runtime like you are doing here. With it setup like you have, when you start your app the form will get loaded and immediately try to query the database. If you wait until the app creates an instance of the form, you can be assured that the database will be ready/available.

So what you'd end up with is something like;

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):

    first_select = TestModelChoiceField(
        queryset=TestModel.objects.none(),
        label="Field One:",
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        self.fields['first_select'].queryset = TestModel.objects.filter(model_attribute__isnull=False)

        self.fields['first_select'].initial = TestModel.objects.filter(
            model_attribute__isnull=False
        ).filter(test_field="Yes").first().team_id
```